# Using xfce4 with kwin on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, xfce, kwin

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop.  I recently installed xfce4 on it and have been using it for a while with everything working.  The other day i tried installing the kde window manager with the command `sudo apt-get install kwin`.  This installed the window manager in working order but i can't open the window manager settings when I right click the title bar of a window.  Every time I click it nothing happens.  I have looked on-line but haven't seen a solution.  Any advice would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I would like to not have to install the entirety of Kubuntu-desktop as well.

Comment: did you configure it and start it following a set of instructions? [this tutorial](http://www.thelinuxrain.com/articles/tutorial-how-to-use-kwin-window-manager-with-xfce) seems to make the full config for xfce

Comment: Yes, I have looked at that tutorial and [this one](http://www.thelinuxrain.com/articles/tutorial-how-to-use-kwin-window-manager-with-xfce).  Kwin automatically starts at login and runs fine.  The problem is with the "Customizing KWin" part which I can't do.  I think the problem is that i don't have kde-workspace which there doesn't seem to be a version of for 16.04

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `kde-cli-tools`:

```
sudo apt-get install kde-cli-tools
```